# how to remove last five characters from all files in current directory in redhot

Tags: linux, unix

> I have hundreds of files and I want to remove last 5 characters from
>   the filenames.

Old filename
[~/AAA]$ ls

1-flat
2-flat
3-flat

expected new files name
[~/AAA]$ ls
1
2
3

> I tried with rename linux command but it's not working as expected

rename 's/.....$//' *
Please advise

Comment: see this 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33279/how-can-i-rename-multiple-files-by-removing-a-character-or-string

Comment: sorry it is not working in redhat (5.11 Tikonga)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one it will be solved. ending (*)  means all file in the directory

```
$ rename 's/.....$//' *
```